# How to capture unhandled exception in C# .NETMF 4.0?

Tags: c#, events, embedded, unhandled-exception, .net-micro-framework

Anyone know how to register an event handler for unhandled exceptions in C# .NETMF 4.0? A Google search reveals nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: What is .NETMF, and why would it matter what programming language you use?

Comment: .NETMF = .NET Micro framework. It's like .NET Compact Framework, but smaller yet.

Comment: @John Saunders, in addition to what @chris12892 said, the .NET Micro Framework (NETMF) only supports C# as of the date of this comment was added.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean .NET 4 then AppDomain.UnhandledException event will give you a chance to clean up but not handle the exception.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx